# Create a nested JSON file from a list of lines that contains the key and value mappings

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, list

Complicated title, let me explain :)

I have an array full of cyclical data inside of it, in this form:

```
id: 0 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Roma
Via Francesco Saverio Altamura
Via: 0
https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/p-147276/
tipologia: Appartamento
m2: 113 m²
piano: 1°, con ascensore
p_edificio: 4 piani
prezzo: € 158.000 - € 270.000
balcone: 0
cantina: 0
terrazza: 0
giardino privato: 0
taverna: 0
esposizione esterna: 0
id: 1 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Roma
Monti
Via degli Zingari
https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/89886713/
tipologia: Appartamento
m2: 113 m²
piano: 1°, con ascensore
p_edificio: 4 piani
prezzo: € 790.000
balcone: 0
cantina: 0
terrazza: 0
giardino privato: 0
taverna: 0
esposizione esterna: 0
```

I added a line to make it visible on where one ends easily. Note that it will not be part of the actual input lines.

What I want to do is to create a JSON file, but not by simply dumping this array inside of the file, I want to create a good structure like the following example:

```
{
"id": "123"
    "city": "Roma",
    "zone": "Via Francesco Saverio Altamura",
    "via": "0",
    "link": "https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/p-147276/",
    "prezzo": "€ 158.000 - € 270.000"
    "addons": [
        {
            "balcone": "0",
            "terrazza": "0",
             and so on...
        },
    ]
}
```

Until now I didn't need to organize it, but now after achieving a good array, with cyclical data that spits out 16 tuple with "key": "value" for every id, I need to organize it and can't understand how to do it how I need it.

Any help on both learning and understanding this process are welcome!

Comment: Do the lines `----------` really appear in the input file? Or you just added them here for visibility?

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano I added them for visibility, I thought I wrote, maybe I forgot, but yeah, mainly for you guys to distinguish easily were one id starts and ends :)

Comment: when you say "cyclical data" does that imply that the data is just collected periodically, or that the data has "circular references"?

Comment: `Via degli Zingari` or is this `Via: degli Zingari`?

Comment: @JonSG the data should be cyclical, but I actually just re-read my code and I dumbed out, so none of both. Basically it collects all the data and makes the list. Sometimes the ads from which I collect data miss one of the things I'm searching for and in that case it's missed in the list, I could implement a solution, but probably don't need it/hope so :)

Comment: When you are saying 16 tuple with "key":"value", do you really mean tuple or dictionary?

Comment: @matszwecja dictionary is the correct term, sorry!

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano if the street (Via is street in italian) is not present it will write down "via: 0", same for the value above and below

Comment: So, following on @NielGodfreyPonciano's question about the dashes, the way to determine the "end of a record" is `esposizione esterna: x` where `x` is some integer right?

Comment: Then you are basicly done, just use json.dumps(yourList, indent=4) and you will get nicely printed formatted json string.

Comment: @JonSG YES EXACTLY! "esposizione esterna: x" will always be the last value and it will either be 0 or 1 depending on the value being found in the website code.

Comment: @matszwecja but will I get the id as the main identifier of the following data? Like in the example I posted?

Comment: If possible then could you please share the raw data?

Comment: @Sabil the raw data is actually the first portion of code

Comment: @MichelangeloAmorusoManzari Why don't you just build the json whilst extracting the orignal data? The intermediate array is redundant and creates an additional parsing step that makes the task harder than it needs to be.

Comment: @MichelangeloAmorusoManzari Is it possible to organize your text file in a dict like format? If yes then it will easier to convert that in json file

Comment: @ekhumoro I would, but I need the array to work with it on another function inside my program, so its easier to work like this and lighter on the server which will run the script...

Comment: @Sabil another user suggested it and I'm working on it right now, thanks :)

Comment: If you have your dict like format ready you can use a python dataclass (https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) to validate your data and handle missing values efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

`json.dumps` from built-in `json` module handles that really nicely, you just need to convert your object to dictionary representing that structure first.

Comment: Ok, so you think I should create a dictionary from the list I created before? Is there a preferred way to do it or a simple straightforward solution? Btw thanks! :)

Comment: List of dictionaries will work just fine.

Comment: Ok thanks! If I manage to do it with this I'll gladly give this as the correct answr :)

Comment: You mentioned you want the id to be main identifier, but in the example provided it actually is in no way different than other attributes like "zone".
If you pass a list of dictionaries you will get something looking like what you provided for each entry. If you pass a dictionary with key being id and value being a dictionary representing single entry instead, id will be main identifier you want

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input data has a fixed order on the fields, this is a solution using regex.

```
import re

data = """
id: 0
Roma
Via Francesco Saverio Altamura
Via: 0
https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/p-147276/
tipologia: Appartamento
m2: 113 m²
piano: 1°, con ascensore
p_edificio: 4 piani
prezzo: € 158.000 - € 270.000
balcone: 0
cantina: 0
terrazza: 0
giardino privato: 0
taverna: 0
esposizione esterna: 0
id: 1
Roma
Monti
Via degli Zingari
https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/89886713/
tipologia: Appartamento
m2: 113 m²
piano: 1°, con ascensore
p_edificio: 4 piani
prezzo: € 790.000
balcone: 0
cantina: 0
terrazza: 0
giardino privato: 0
taverna: 0
esposizione esterna: 0
"""

data_fixed_keys = [
    "id",
    "city",
    "zone",
    "via",
    "link",
    "tipologia",
    "m2",
    "piano",
    "p_edificio",
    "prezzo",
    "balcone",
    "cantina",
    "terrazza",
    "giardino privato",
    "taverna",
    "esposizione esterna",
]

matches = re.findall(
    r"id: (?P<id>.*)\s+"
    "(?P<city>.*)\s+"
    "(?P<zone>.*)\s+"
    "(?P<via>.*)\s+"
    "(?P<link>.*)\s+"
    "tipologia: (?P<tipologia>.*)\s+"
    "m2: (?P<m2>.*)\s+"
    "piano: (?P<piano>.*)\s+"
    "p_edificio: (?P<p_edificio>.*)\s+"
    "prezzo: (?P<prezzo>.*)\s+"
    "balcone: (?P<balcone>.*)\s+"
    "cantina: (?P<cantina>.*)\s+"
    "terrazza: (?P<terrazza>.*)\s+"
    "giardino privato: (?P<giardino_privato>.*)\s+"
    "taverna: (?P<taverna>.*)\s+"
    "esposizione esterna: (?P<esposizione_esterna>.*)",
    data,
)

""" Option 1: Dictionary JSON """
data_json = {}
for match in matches:
    current_dict = dict(zip(data_fixed_keys[1:5], match[1:5]))
    current_dict["addons"] = dict(zip(data_fixed_keys[5:], match[5:]))
    current_dict["prezzo"] = current_dict["addons"].pop("prezzo")
    data_json[match[0]] = current_dict

""" Option 2: List JSON
data_json = []
for match in matches:
    current_dict = dict(zip(data_fixed_keys[:5], match[:5]))
    current_dict["addons"] = dict(zip(data_fixed_keys[5:], match[5:]))
    current_dict["prezzo"] = current_dict["addons"].pop("prezzo")
    data_json.append(current_dict)
"""

print(data_json)
```

Output (pretty printed)

```
# If using Option 1 (Dictionary JSON)
{
    "0": {
        "city": "Roma",
        "zone": "Via Francesco Saverio Altamura",
        "via": "Via: 0",
        "link": "https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/p-147276/",
        "addons": {
            "tipologia": "Appartamento",
            "m2": "113 m\u00b2",
            "piano": "1\u00b0, con ascensore",
            "p_edificio": "4 piani",
            "balcone": "0",
            "cantina": "0",
            "terrazza": "0",
            "giardino privato": "0",
            "taverna": "0",
            "esposizione esterna": "0"
        },
        "prezzo": "\u20ac 158.000 - \u20ac 270.000"
    },
    "1": {
        "city": "Roma",
        "zone": "Monti",
        "via": "Via degli Zingari",
        "link": "https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/89886713/",
        "addons": {
            "tipologia": "Appartamento",
            "m2": "113 m\u00b2",
            "piano": "1\u00b0, con ascensore",
            "p_edificio": "4 piani",
            "balcone": "0",
            "cantina": "0",
            "terrazza": "0",
            "giardino privato": "0",
            "taverna": "0",
            "esposizione esterna": "0"
        },
        "prezzo": "\u20ac 790.000"
    }
}

# If using Option 2 (List JSON)
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "city": "Roma",
        "zone": "Via Francesco Saverio Altamura",
        "via": "Via: 0",
        "link": "https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/p-147276/",
        "addons": {
            "tipologia": "Appartamento",
            "m2": "113 m\u00b2",
            "piano": "1\u00b0, con ascensore",
            "p_edificio": "4 piani",
            "balcone": "0",
            "cantina": "0",
            "terrazza": "0",
            "giardino privato": "0",
            "taverna": "0",
            "esposizione esterna": "0"
        },
        "prezzo": "\u20ac 158.000 - \u20ac 270.000"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "city": "Roma",
        "zone": "Monti",
        "via": "Via degli Zingari",
        "link": "https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/89886713/",
        "addons": {
            "tipologia": "Appartamento",
            "m2": "113 m\u00b2",
            "piano": "1\u00b0, con ascensore",
            "p_edificio": "4 piani",
            "balcone": "0",
            "cantina": "0",
            "terrazza": "0",
            "giardino privato": "0",
            "taverna": "0",
            "esposizione esterna": "0"
        },
        "prezzo": "\u20ac 790.000"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi, what if I made a dictionary and have the list with all the info? Is there a good way to dump the list in the dictionary placing the values in the correct positions relative to the correct keys?

Comment: Could you give an example? Since the input text contains more than 1 record (marked by the field `id`), then here you can see that the result is already a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary is for 1 id. The keys are also ordered the same way as the original text (except for `prezzo` because it was mixed with the other `addons`).

Comment: Or do you mean to say that instead of `[{"id":"0", "city": "Roma"}, {"id":"1", "city": "Paris"}]`, it should be `{"0": {"city": "Roma"}, "1": {"city": "Paris"}}` ?

Comment: @MichelangeloAmorusoManzari Could you check my updated answer if it better fits what you need? I changed the output to a dictionary with the `id` as the key.

Comment: Hi Niel, I checked it and it's not working well for my case, thanks anyways and sorry for not answering, really trying to find a good solution!