# How to create JSON file with nested values from simple Python list

Tags: python, json, list

I have a list like this one:

```
id: 0 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Roma
Via Francesco Saverio Altamura
Via: 0
https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/p-147276/
tipologia: Appartamento
m2: 113 m²
piano: 1°, con ascensore
p_edificio: 4 piani
prezzo: € 158.000 - € 270.000
balcone: 0
cantina: 0
terrazza: 0
giardino privato: 0
taverna: 0
esposizione esterna: 0
id: 1 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Roma
Monti
Via degli Zingari
https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/89886713/
tipologia: Appartamento
m2: 113 m²
piano: 1°, con ascensore
p_edificio: 4 piani
prezzo: € 790.000
balcone: 0
cantina: 0
terrazza: 0
giardino privato: 0
taverna: 0
esposizione esterna: 0
```

and what I want to do is to create a JSON file in this form, with nested objects, like this:

```
{
"id": "123": [
    "city": "Roma",
    "zone": "Via Francesco Saverio Altamura",
    "via": "0",
    "link": "https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/p-147276/",
    "prezzo": "€ 158.000 - € 270.000"
    "addons": [
        {
            "balcone": "0",
            "terrazza": "0",
             and so on...
        },
    ]
]
}
```

What I'm having problems with is the key-value part.

I can do a simple: `json.dump...` but it will dump one item list per JSON object.
I instead would like to have id as the main object and all the other info inside it.

So that is I have 300 items in my list and I have 5 IDs, then it all comes down to 5 objects, each containing the items belonging to that id.

Any simple solution you guys/gals know? Thanks!

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: The expected output isn't valid JSON.

Comment: this syntax: `"id": "123": [` is not valid in JSON

Comment: Also `[ ... ]` can't contain `key: value` pairs, those need to be inside `{ ... }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a nested JSON file from a list of lines that contains the key and value mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031565/create-a-nested-json-file-from-a-list-of-lines-that-contains-the-key-and-value-m)

Comment: Make a dictionary where the `id` values are the keys, and the values are lists of dictionaries.

Comment: @Sabil That question didn't say that he wants to group multiple objects with the same ID.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Barmar and James this was more of an example of the structure, I didn't explain myself sorry!

Comment: @Sabil and I didn't find a good solution and so I redid my code to find a better solution and maybe this question is more suitable for this problem :)

Comment: @Barmar understood the difference, thanks for noticing it :)

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Sabil I have changed my code so that the info from every ad is in the list ordered, actually very similar to before. The change I want to try is to use the id as the object and put all the next items of the list inside the id until it finds the next item called "id". When it does it creates a new object and does the same.

Comment: @Barmar on the dictionary solution, I have repeating values, can't use them, good try though :)

Comment: That's why the values are lists.

Comment: {"123": [ { ...}, {...}], ...}`

Comment: @Barmar can we open a chat and discuss it there? Easier... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use "Option 2: List JSON" from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69032525/1491895 to convert your input to a list of dictionaries. Then you can group them by common `id` values.

```
dict_json = {}
for d in list_json:
    dict_json.setdefault(d['id'], []).append(d)
```

This will create a result like:

```
{
    "123": [{
        "id": "123",
        "city": "Roma",
        "zone": "Via Francesco Saverio Altamura",
        "via": "Via: 0",
        "link": "https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/p-147276/",
        "addons": {
            "tipologia": "Appartamento",
            "m2": "113 m\u00b2",
            "piano": "1\u00b0, con ascensore",
            "p_edificio": "4 piani",
            "balcone": "0",
            "cantina": "0",
            "terrazza": "0",
            "giardino privato": "0",
            "taverna": "0",
            "esposizione esterna": "0"
        },
        "prezzo": "\u20ac 158.000 - \u20ac 270.000"
    },
    {
        "id": "123",
        "city": "Roma",
        "zone": "Monti",
        "via": "Via degli Zingari",
        "link": "https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/89886713/",
        "addons": {
            "tipologia": "Appartamento",
            "m2": "113 m\u00b2",
            "piano": "1\u00b0, con ascensore",
            "p_edificio": "4 piani",
            "balcone": "0",
            "cantina": "0",
            "terrazza": "0",
            "giardino privato": "0",
            "taverna": "0",
            "esposizione esterna": "0"
        },
        "prezzo": "\u20ac 790.000"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a solution like this:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "values": 
    {
        "city": "Roma",
        "zone": "Via Francesco Saverio Altamura",
        "via": "0",
        "link": "https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/p-147276/",
        "prezzo": "€ 158.000 - € 270.000"
        "addons": 
            {
                "balcone": "0",
                "terrazza": "0",
                and so on...
            }
    }
}
```

creating a dictionary as above and convert it to a json with *json* library with:

```
import json


data = {
    "id": "123",
    "values": 
    {
        "city": "Roma",
        "zone": "Via Francesco Saverio Altamura",
        "via": "0",
        "link": "https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/p-147276/",
        "prezzo": "€ 158.000 - € 270.000"
        "addons": 
            {
                "balcone": "0",
                "terrazza": "0",
                and so on...
            }
    }
}

json_data = json.dumps(data, indent = 4)

print(json_data)
```

(this exemple is made to printout your json, you can produce a json file if you prefer.